# How to android camera2 feed the preview frame data to OpenCV for processing

Tags: android, android-camera2

I want to do some image processing in the camera preview, such as grayscale
In the old camera api is easy, but transplanted into camera2 api, i do not know how to do it

```
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera cam) {
// custom image data processing
}
```

I've tried to get the frame from here (as suggested in the answer to the question):

```
private final ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener mOnImageAvailableListener
        = new ImageReader.OnImageAvailableListener() {

    @Override
    public void onImageAvailable(ImageReader reader) {

        Log.d("Img", "onImageAvailable");
        mBackgroundHandler.post(new ImageSaver(reader.acquireNextImage(), mFile));
    }

};
```

his was not useful, as the callback is called only after the user performed capture of image

Comment: What isn't working, are you getting an error? What is your desired result vs the actual result

Answer (score 4):

This sample from Google https://github.com/googlesamples/android-HdrViewfinder gives the basic of what you need to do.

Summary:

1) Add a *Surface* to the output of the camera

2) Listen to updates to this surface, in the above example it happens in *ViewfinderProcessor.java*

The above example uses 2 surfaces for a fake HDR preview but you should easily be able to clean the example up to only use 1 surface. Also the example uses a custom Render Script kernel for processing, you don't need to use that. You can easily catch the buffer type *Allocation* in ViewfinderProcessor.java to get a byte array as in the old Camera API.

Comment: It's a good practice to copy-paste the snippet of code that actually solves the question. Links may become broken in the future rendering the answer unhelpful. Additionally pasting the snippet makes it much easier for others as well as the original asker to get the solution they are after, and keeps all the relevant information (problem with solution) in one place - which is the purpose of SO.

Comment: et_l : if that link breaks in the future a code snippet won't help much; the example app runs to 60+ files.